# How to do nested select in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, select, nested

How does one, in MongoDB, implement something like the following SQL statement?

```
select count(*),t1.a,t1.b 
from   t1, t2 
where (t1.id = t2.t1_id) 
and   (t2.t1_id in (select id
                    from t1
                    order by id desc
                    limit 10)) 
group by 2,3 
order by 1 desc
```

I figured out how to do everything except the nested select.

I'm currently running the outer select in a loop using `"$in"` for each value of the nested select. Java code is as follows:

```
BasicDBList t1List = new BasicDBList();
DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", t1List);
DBObject t2Query = new BasicDBObject("t1s", inClause);
DBObject nextt2;

for (int query = 0; query < 10; query++)
{
    System.out.printf("Running query %d - ", query);
    DBCursor top_ten_t1s = t1Coll.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("v", -1)).limit(10);
    while (top_ten_t1s.hasNext())
    {
        nextt2 = top_ten_t1s.next();
        t1List.clear();
        t1List.add(new Long(nextt2.get("_id").toString()));
        int theCount = t2Coll.find(t2Query).count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one query in MongoDB. You'll need to read the result of the inner query into memory first (which it sounds like you're already doing):

```
var ids = t1.find().sort( { _id: -1 } ).limit(10);
```

And apply this result to the outer query.

Comment: I'm "apply"ing the result by running a Java, I'm using the Java driver, loop, and running the outer query 10 times.  Is there a way to run the loop inside MongoDB, and output the results?  Would it be significantly faster?

Comment: @user2592857 can you please post your Java code? And no, it wouldn't be any faster if you did it inside MongoDB (it would be a shell script with similar performance).

Comment: BasicDBList t1List = new BasicDBList();
 DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", t1List);
 DBObject t2Query = new BasicDBObject("t1s", inClause);
 DBObject nextt2;
 for (int query = 0; query < 10; query++) {
  System.out.printf("Running query %d - ", query);

  DBCursor top_ten_t1s = t1Coll.find()
    .sort(new BasicDBObject("v", -1))
    .limit(10);
 
  while (top_ten_t1s.hasNext()) {
   nextt2 = top_ten_t1s.next();
   t1List.clear();
   t1List.add(new Long(nextt2.get("_id").toString()));
   int theCount = t2Coll.find(t2Query).count();
  }
 }

Comment: user2592857, please don't add the solution as a comment, add it to the original question.